# Identify Object dependencies between a SQL Server database and Oracle over a Linked Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, search, linked-server, openquery

I'm working with a SQL Server database Engine, which has a database containing approximately 2,000 Views. The majority of these Views use the OpenQuery statement to select data from an Oracle database via a Linked Server.

I have a new requirement to identify the dependencies between the SQL Server Views & the Oracle Objects referenced in the OpenQuery statements. This is not going to be a one-off requirement, so I will need to be able to refresh this on occasion. The Objects within Oracle change frequently and new Views are regularly added or modified in SQL Server too.

Some of the Views (about 0.5% of them) are structured as below (without OpenQuery):

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[SampleViewType1] AS

SELECT  ColX,
        ColY
FROM OracleLinkedServerName..OracleSchemaName.SampleOracleTable1
```

For these Views, I have stumbled across a useful query which can pick up the Views and the Oracle Objects it references.

```
SELECT 
    Distinct 
    referenced_Server_name As LinkedServerName,
    referenced_schema_name AS LinkedServerSchema,
    referenced_database_name AS LinkedServerDB,
    referenced_entity_name As LinkedServerTable,
    OBJECT_NAME (referencing_id) AS ObjectUsingLinkedServer
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies
WHERE referenced_database_name IS NOT NULL
And referenced_Server_name = 'OracleLinkedServerName'
```

It can give me results like below:

[sys.sql_expression_dependencies result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhlPe.png)

However, the majority of the Views are structured as per the sample below and use OpenQuery. Unfortunately, `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` does not pick up these types of references.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[SampleViewType2] As

SELECT 
    ColA,
    ColB
FROM OPENQUERY 
(
    OracleLinkedServerName, 
    'SELECT *
    FROM SampleOracleTable2
    WHERE TestDate BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, ''month'') AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)'
);
```

Has anyone any suggestions on how I may obtain this information? At the moment, I'm not sure if it is possible. I'm open to using other technologies outside SQL such as C#, VB, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the view definition and check if the text has the name 'OracleLinkedServerName'. Please refer below query

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(CONCAT (
                    ss.name
                    ,'.'
                    ,so.name
                    ))) [Definition]
        ,so.name
    FROM sys.objects so
    JOIN sys.schemas ss ON so.schema_id = ss.schema_id
    WHERE type = 'V'
    ) a
WHERE a.DEFINITION LIKE '%OracleLinkedServerName%'
```

Query to get all the objects that are used in the view definition

```
DECLARE @objects TABLE (name NVARCHAR(max))

INSERT INTO @objects
SELECT so.name
FROM sys.objects so

-- You have to do this manually for all the oracle object
-- copy all your objects in excel and use excel funtions to form this
-- Remember last select should not have UNION All
INSERT INTO @objects
SELECT 'Oracle object 1'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Oracle object 2'

SELECT *
FROM @objects so
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(CONCAT (
                        ss.name
                        ,'.'
                        ,so.name
                        ))) [Definition]
            ,so.name
        FROM sys.objects so
        JOIN sys.schemas ss ON so.schema_id = ss.schema_id
        WHERE type = 'V'
        ) a
    WHERE a.DEFINITION LIKE '%OracleLinkedServerName%'
    ) a ON a.DEFINITION LIKE '%' + so.name + '%'
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It's a step in the right direction. However, I still need to identify the Oracle objects used in the OpenQuery section of the Query Definition from this result. I wonder is there any function to extract table names from a Sql Query statement?

Comment: What are the objects that you need to extract? I assume only tables?

Comment: Inside the OpenQuery statement there may be Tables and/or Views used.

Comment: I have added a new query, can you check if that could help you.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this does not pick up the Oracle objects. :-(

Comment: Are you using sql-server or oracle server? Yeah, the query doesn't pick the oracle objects

Comment: You can do one approach, get all the oracle objects that you have with "," separated and use it. How oracle objects do you think of? I just got another solution. I'll update it

Comment: Updated the second query, check once if that can help